# Magento2 : How to create custom less file in magento 2 for particular store?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, less

In Magento2, how to create custom.less file for a particular store ? 
i created custom themes like theme1, theme2 and theme3 in magento2 
and also i created custom.less file only in theme but when i hit the command to compile this less file but is generated in all themes folders 
i am only create this custom.less file in theme

these steps i follow to compile

first : i am created **custom.less** file
second: i am run these command to generate from custom.less to csutom.css
         - **php bin/magento setup:static:content:deploy -f**
         - **php bin/magento cache:clean**
conculsion : but this custom.css file generated in all themes.